Open mapping theorem for spaces of holomorphic functions
In studying several complex variables, I came across an exercise in what is effectively an application of the open mapping theorem for Frechet spaces without actually using said theorem. The situation is as follows. Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be a connected holomorphically convex set and suppose that $\Omega' \subset \Omega$ is an open set for which the restriction map $\rho : \mathscr{O}(\Omega) \to \mathscr{O}(\Omega')$ between the spaces of holomorphic functions with the compact-open topology is bijective. Then $\rho$ is a homeomorphism.
The exercise goes through 3 steps before we can conclude that $\rho$ is a homeomorphism:

$f(\Omega) = f(\Omega')$ for all $f \in \mathscr{O}(\Omega)$,
every compact set $K \subset \Omega$ has a corresponding compact set $L \subset \Omega'$ such that $K \subset \widehat{L}_{\mathscr{O}(\Omega)}$,
a sequence $(f_j)$ in $\mathscr{O}(\Omega)$ converges on compact subsets of $\Omega$ if and only if it converges on compact subsets of $\Omega'$.

I have managed to get through step 1 and using step 2, I have managed to get through step 3 as well. But I seem to be very stuck on step 2 itself. What I have tried is to define
$$L' = \left\{z \in \Omega' : |f(z)| \leq \sup_K|g| \ \forall f \in \mathscr{O}(\Omega')\right\},$$
where $g$ is the unique holomorphic function in $\mathscr{O}(\Omega)$ such that $\rho(g) = f$. Then $L' \subset \widehat{K}_{\mathscr{O}(\Omega)}$ and so taking closures in $\Omega$ implies that $cl_\Omega(L')$ is compact since $\Omega$ is holomorphically convex. My guess is then that $L = cl_\Omega(L')$ is the compact set the exercise is looking for, but I haven't been able to show that $cl_\Omega(L')$ is contained in $\Omega'$, nor have I been able to show that $K \subset \widehat{L}_{\mathscr{O}(\Omega)}$. I assume that I am supposed to use part 1 in some capacity, but I've only managed to deduce that $g(K) \subset f(\Omega')$ whenever $\rho(g) = f$. Am I on the right track, and if so, could I get some hints on how to proceed? Thanks!

The restriction map is a continuous linear operator between Fréchet spaces. If it is assumed to be bijective it is automatically an isomorphism (in the category of Fréchet spaces, i.e., it has a continuous linear inverse).

@Jochen right, but I think what this exercise is trying to do is to prove the same thing in this specific setting without resorting to knowing this fact from functional analysis. For example, I wouldn't need to know that I have a holomorphically convex domain if I could apply this fact from functional analysis, so I'm treating this exercise as if it's an exercise in hulls rather than an exercise in functional analysis.
